# Build reference to XAML element up from string

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make my references to my XAML objects dynamic based on the sender ClassId.

I have an ActivityIndicator called "spinner_origin" & I control whether it is visible in c# with a simple

```
spinner_origin.Isvisible = true;
```

How would I go about making the spinner_origin bit dynamic and build it up through a combination of strings? I also have a second AI called spinner_destination & I can pass in the origin or destination part through a ClassID. Unfortunately this doesnt work:

```
"spinner_" + "origin".IsVisible = true;
```

I've also tried building the reference to the AI separately, which also failed:

```
ActivityIndicator act_indicator = (ActivityIndicator) "spinner_" + "origin";
act_indicator.IsVisible = true
```

Comment: You could use `FindByName` in the codebehind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to shanranm for their answer, the solution to this was:

```
 ActivityIndicator act_indicator = this.FindByName<ActivityIndicator>("spinner_" + "origin");
```

Obviously origin can now be set to a variable (or in my case the ClassId of the sender).